# What size is this hole?

Tags: screws, hole

I  Have a tool for measuring the sizes of holes and screws but I don’t know what size is listed as 10 in the image below.  Across from it the row in question is listed as INCH.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A #10 screw will be a close fit in the 10 hole and is approximately 3/16" in diameter. The tolerance on a #10 screw ranges from about 0.182" to 0.190". Gauges of this kind are not intended to make precise measurements, but to easily identify fasteners.

Answer (score 3):

If you are speaking of the holes marked 4,5,6,8,10, these are small bolt sizes. There is 1 size missing and that is #12. Most sizes with diameters less than 3/16" are listed as number sizes.  I hope this helps and is what you are asking about.

Comment: As @d george stated, diameter size smaller than 3/16" are designated by a one or two digit numbers as shown on your gauge.  Do not expect these number to translate to a nice clean factions.  Only #5 matches up to 1/8",  In a hardware store, you will see the small bolts and screws organized by size 6, 8, 10 and 12 as the most common sizes.